# syncing html with w3m

Tags: html, w3m

How can I split Emacs to two buffers, one for html and the other for w3m so that when I save the html it refreshes the w3m buffer. Also, when I press E in the w3m buffer it takes me to the corresponding position in the html buffer. Exactly like the sync between tex and pdf buffers in pdf-view.